# SQL Select Rows with Highest Version

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I am trying to query the following table:

| ID | ConsentTitle | ConsentIdentifier | Version | DisplayOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FooTitle | foo1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | FooTitle 2 | foo1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Bar Title | bar1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Bar Title 2 | bar1 | 2 | 4 |

My table has entries with unique ConsentTemplateIdentifier. I want to bring back only the rows with the highest version number for that particular unique Identifier...

| ID | ConsentTitle | ConsentIdentifier | Version | DisplayOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FooTitle 2 | foo1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Bar Title 2 | bar1 | 2 | 4 |

My current query doesn't seem to work. It is telling me:

> Column 'ConsentTemplates.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

```
Select Distinct ID,ConsentTitle, DisplayOrder,  ConsentTemplateIdentifier, MAX(Version) as Version
from FooDocs
group by ConsentTemplateIdentifier
```

How do I select the rows distinctly which have the highest Version number for their respective ConsentTemplateIdentifiers ordered by their display order?

Any help would be really appreciated. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY` works, but effectively invokes the sub-query for every row in in your table, then expend effort to de-duplicate the results with DISTINCT, resulting in a semi-cartesian-product / triangular-join.

It is usually much more efficient just to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and avoid the implicit join all together...

```
WITH
  sorted_by_version AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
   ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER (
       PARTITION BY ConsentTemplateIdentifier
           ORDER BY version DESC
     )
       AS version_ordinal
  FROM
    ConsentTemplates
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted_by_version
WHERE
  version_ordinal = 1
ORDER BY
  DisplayOrder
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.*
FROM FooDocs fd
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM FooDocs
             WHERE ConsentIdentifier = fd.ConsentIdentifier
             ORDER BY Version DESC) ca
```

If your unique identifier has it's own table.

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM ConsentTable ct
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM FooDocs
             WHERE ConsentIdentifier = ct.Identifier
             ORDER BY Version DESC) ca
```

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to Derrick's answer, I was able to get the data back the way I wanted to see it using `CROSS APPLY`

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ca.*
FROM ConsentTemplates fd
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM ConsentTemplates
             WHERE ConsentTemplateIdentifier = fd.ConsentTemplateIdentifier
             ORDER BY Version DESC) ca
             order by DisplayOrder
```